# Selectize plugin in free-jqGrid does not display all values

Tags: selectize.js, free-jqgrid

I'm using free-jqGrid 4.13.5 and selectize 0.12.4.

I'm trying to apply selectize on my dropdowns in inline edit. But only one value is displayed in the dropdown.

```
  editoptions: {
                  value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intime",
                  defaultValue: "Intime",
                  dataInit: function(element) {
                                $(element).selectize();
                            }
```

It works if I'm using select2, instead of selectize.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/henrik79/90hj0wd9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the parent of drop-down of selectize. To fix the problem I suggest you to use `dropdownParent: "body"` option:

```js
dataInit: function(element) {
    $(element).selectize({
        dropdownParent: "body"
    });
}
```

The fixed demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/90hj0wd9/2/ uses the changes. I added some other CSS properties to improve the look of the results:

```css
.selectize-dropdown-content {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif
}
.selectize-input {
  min-height: 1.7em;
}
.selectize-input {
    padding: .4em .3em;
}
.DataTD .selectize-control {
    height: 24px;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td {
    border-color: inherit;
 }
```